# What is the deepest cause of the such high specific heat capacity of water?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, degrees-of-freedom

Yes, I know about the hydrogen bridges. But I think, it isn't the deepest cause. Anyway, they are only second-order bindings, although quite strong.

I think, somehow should have the water a significant number of "hidden degrees of freedom", or some like internal structure with a lot of degrees of freedom. But it is only my naive intuition.

So, what is the deepest cause?

Comment: Water is a complex topic; my personal suggestion is that you enrich your question with more context.  I don't think I'll have enough info now to answer the question either way, but I think the added info would contribute to the discussion and future considerations.